# Can there be two high elves in Dungeons & Dragons?

Tags: character-creation, dungeons-and-dragons, races, elf

I'm trying to make my own character sheet but I'm lost. One of the main characters is already a high elf; does that mean I can't be one?

Comment: Hi there! Do you have access to the Player's Handbook, or other published material? Is there a reason you believe there can't be more than one of a race in any given party? While you here, have you checked out the [tour]? It will help you get oriented with the Stack :)

Comment: no actually, i just got told to make a character sheet and i thought since he was a main character, others couldn't be from the same race. i've never done this before so i will definitely check it out. thank you for your help Jason_c_o

Comment: Are you playing the most recent edition (D&D 5e, with a player's handbook [that looks like this](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_playershandbook)) or another?

Comment: What do you mean by "main character"?

Comment: If I may quote a very famous line in the swords and sorcery movie  [Highlander](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091203/) ... *there can be only one!*  Also, who has told you that there is a main character?

Comment: I don't think this is a strange question at all; there are games, such as Dragon Union, Dungeon World and Apocalypse World, where the character options are meant to be unique. Normal Dungeons & Dragons is not one of them and there can be any number of high elves in a party. Welcome to D&D♥

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can still be a high elf.

Dungeons & Dragons characters aren't expected to be unique in every facet in any edition I can think of: you can have two high elves, or even a party of all high elves if that's what you all want to do.

Different races can bring new features to the group it doesn't already have access to, so that's something to consider, but wouldn't prevent you from sharing the same race as someone else.

Comment: Maybe also mention something about the “main character” thing in the question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not actually sure what I would/should mention about that.